# Change image position using variable + buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to change the square's position (placeholder images) based on a variable, that I would like to change when the right and left buttons are clicked. I am not sure what I've done wrong, not even the debug button to show me if the variable is changing will work. Code below (Idk if the CSS is really needed but I added it anyway).

edit: Here's a link to the code https://codepen.io/linelessmail/pen/yLNpGve

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="left" class="button" style="font-size :40px;height:100px;width:300px">Left</button>
<button id="right" class="button" style="font-size : 40px;height:100px;width:300px">Right</button> 
<button onClick="test()">DEBUG</button>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Blended_colour_wheel.svg/300px-Blended_colour_wheel.svg.png" alt="Wheel" width="800"height="800" id="wheel">


<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Square_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Square_-_black_simple.svg.png" alt="square" width="200"height="200" id="square">
```

CSS:

```
#right {
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 1000px;
}

#left {
    position:absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 1000px;
}

#wheel {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    transform-origin: centre;
}

#square {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 1000px;
    transform-origin: centre;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var deg = 0;
  var position = 1;

  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#left")) {
      deg = deg - 32.7272727273;
      var position = position - 1;
      if (position == 1) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
}
if (position == 2) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
} 
if (position == 3) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 4) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 5) {
var position = 1
} 
    } else {
      deg = deg + 32.7272727273;
      var position = position + 1;
      if (position == 1) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
}
if (position == 2) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
} 
if (position == 3) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 4) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 5) {
var position = 1
} 
    }

    $("#wheel").css({
      "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-ms-animation:": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-o-animation": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      transform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg)"

    });

    function test(click){
    alert("Position variable is " + position);
}
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share demo?

Comment: @vadivela whoops yeah here it is! https://codepen.io/linelessmail/pen/yLNpGve

Comment: @linelessmail Did you debug the Javascript code and find out what the variable position value is? I assume that it will have value as "NaN" based on your declaration. Also, you have set its value as 1 and then your subtracting from 1 which results as "0", hence none of the if condition gets hit and so the square does not move left when you hit left button. You could try correcting your Javascript code.

Comment: @TheGaME I don't know how to see what the variable is without the button (but it's not working), but thank you for pointing that out abt the left button I completely overlooked that! Could that be fixed with a  "if (position == 0) {
var position = 4 }" like I did with the cap of 5?

Comment: @linelessmail If your using Chrome browser for testing then have a look at this page to learn how to debug Javascript using developer tools. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood the problem
I think you are mixing javascript with jquery.
the onclick function is from javascript and you are adding it as if it were jquery on the other hand you had a lot of position variables that I have passed to global scope

Cannot find the test function because it is inside the jquery I have sadaco and it works correctly
Hope this can help you

```js
var position = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var deg = 0;
  

  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#left")) {
      deg = deg - 32.7272727273;
      position = position - 1;
      if (position == 1) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
}
if (position == 2) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
} 
if (position == 3) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 4) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 5) {
position = 1
} 
    } else {
      deg = deg + 32.7272727273;
      position = position + 1;
      if (position == 1) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
}
if (position == 2) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '400px';
} 
if (position == 3) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1000px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 4) {
square.style.marginLeft = '1300px';
square.style.marginLeft = '600px';
} 
if (position == 5) {
position = 1
} 
    }
    
    $("#wheel").css({
      "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-ms-animation:": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      "-o-animation": "rotate(" + deg + "deg)",
      transform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg)"
      
    });
    

  });
});
    function test(click){
    alert("Position variable is " + position);
}
```

```css
#right {
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 1000px;
}

#left {
    position:absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 1000px;
}

#wheel {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    transform-origin: centre;
}

#square {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 1000px;
    transform-origin: centre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="left" class="button" style="font-size :40px;height:100px;width:300px">Left</button>
<button id="right" class="button" style="font-size : 40px;height:100px;width:300px">Right</button> 
<button onClick="test()">DEBUG</button>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Blended_colour_wheel.svg/300px-Blended_colour_wheel.svg.png" alt="Wheel" width="800"height="800" id="wheel">


<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Square_-_black_simple.svg/1200px-Square_-_black_simple.svg.png" alt="square" width="200"height="200" id="square">
```

Comment: Ah okay, I'm pretty new and didn't really know the difference between JavaScript and JQuery. Thank you so much! Really helps a lot, I was stuck in a rut for a while there!